# Is that possible to show split container inside dialog/modal dialog in dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo, splitcontainer, dijit.dialog

I was trying to add SplitContainer inside dialog programatically, I am not able to success it.

Could anyone please suggest me that is it possible to add SplitContainer inside Dialog? if yes please share the me the sample if you have anything.

Thanks
Murugan

The popover widget is our own widget and derived from dojo dialog.

```
define("storm/service/serviceErrorDeploy/serviceErrorDeploy", ["dojo/_base/declare",
        "dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore",
        "xwt/widget/table/Table",
        "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
        "dijit/tree/ForestStoreModel",
        "xwt/widget/layout/Popover",
        "dojo/_base/lang",
        "dojo/dom",
        "dojo/i18n!storm/nls/actions",
        "xwt/widget/table/GlobalToolbar",
        "xwt/widget/tree/Tree",
         'dojo/dom-construct',
         'dojo/query',
         "dojo/_base/array"      
        ], function(declare, ItemFileWriteStore, Table,ContentPane, ForestStoreModel, Popover,lang,dom,nls,GlobalToolbar,Tree,domConstruct,query,array){
    return declare("storm.topology.serviceErrorDeploy.widget.serviceErrorDeploy", [Popover], {
        i18n: nls,
        id:"serviceErrorPop",
        pinnable:false,
        baseClass: "serviceErrorDeploy",
        errorProvisioningDetailsTable:null,
        errorProvisioningDetailsCPane:null,
        summaryData : null,
        url : '/webacs/api/v1/data/DeviceConfigDeploymentStatus.json?.full=true&cfsId=',
        tableData:null,
        resizable:true,
        treeArray: [],
        postCreate: function(){
            this.inherited(arguments);
            if(dijit.byId('errorProvisioningDetailsCPaneID')){
                try {                   
                    dijit.byId('errorProvisioningDetailsCPaneID').destroy();                    
                }catch(err) {console.log(err);}
            } 
            var tableTrs = query('.serviceErrorDeployPopup');
            tableTrs.forEach(lang.hitch(this,function(obj){ 
                var node = query('.xwtPopoverClose',obj)[0];
                if(node && node !=undefined)
                    node.click();
            }));
        },
        setValues: function(values, cell){
            this.inherited(arguments);
            this.setAttribute('title',values.name);
            this.url += values["@id"]?values["@id"]:values.version>=0?values.provisionedCfsId:values.discoveredCfsId;
            this.createWidgetStructure();
        },
        createWidgetStructure:function(){
            this.splitterPane = new  xwt.widget.layout.SplitContainer({id:'errorDetailsSplitContainer',useFullViewPort:true}, this.containerNode);
            this.errorProvisioningDetailsCPane = new ContentPane({
                id: "errorProvisioningDetailsCPaneID",
                region: "top",
                style:"height:100%;border: 1px white solid;overflow:hidden;"
            });                 
            this.errorDetailsTreeCPane = new ContentPane({
                id: "errorDetailsTreeCPaneID",
                region: "center",
                style:"height:270px;border: 1px white solid;"
            });
            this.splitterPane.addChild(this.errorProvisioningDetailsCPane);
            this.splitterPane.addChild(this.errorDetailsTreeCPane);
            this.splitterPane.startup();
            this.splitterPane.resize();         
        },
        hide: function(evt) {
            this.inherited(arguments);
            if (this.errorProvisioningDetailsCPane) {
                this.errorProvisioningDetailsCPane.destroyRecursive();
                this.errorProvisioningDetailsCPane = null;
            }
            this.treeArray = [];
        },
        destroy: function(){
            this.inherited(arguments);
            if (this.errorProvisioningDetailsCPane) {
                this.errorProvisioningDetailsCPane.destroyRecursive();
                this.errorProvisioningDetailsCPane = null;
            }
            this.treeArray = [];
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you can share your code here.

Comment: code added as  not able to attache the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that  the `SplitContainer` is deprecated , so you should use other layout instead , in this case using `BorderContainer` and use the `liveSplitter:true` may help you ,

Please see  this working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/75s07zLv/2/) .

and a working snippet :

```js
require(["dijit/layout/BorderContainer","dijit/layout/ContentPane","dijit/Dialog","dijit/registry", "dojo/dom","dojo/on","dijit/form/Button","dojo/ready"],
  function(BorderContainer,ContentPane,Dialog,registry,dom,On,Button,ready){
      ready(function(){
         myDialog = new Dialog({
              title: "My Dialog",
              content: "Test content.",
              style: "width: 300px"
          },"dialog");
          
          var borderContainer = new BorderContainer({
           style:"height: 300px; width: 300px",
             gutters:true, 
             liveSplitters:true
          });
          
          var cp1 = new ContentPane({
              region: "center",
              splitter:true,
              style: "width: 100px",
              content: "content 1"
          });
          borderContainer.addChild(cp1);

          var cp2 = new ContentPane({
            splitter:true,
              region: "right",
              content: "content 2"
          });
          borderContainer.addChild(cp2);
          
          myDialog.addChild(borderContainer);
          
          On(registry.byId("btn"),"click",function(e){
           myDialog.show();
          })
          
          
        });    
    }
);
```

```html
<script>
dojoConfig = {
  isDebug: true,
  parseOnLoad: true,
};
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body class="claro">
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="btn"> click me </div>
<div id="dialog"></div>
</body>
```